# Remove Object from array by object value in php

Tags: php, laravel

```
$followers = [['id'=>0], ['id'=>1]];
```

So, assuming I have this array, what would be the best way to remove the object by it's id?

That's what i came up with

```
foreach($followers as $key=>$follower){
    if($follower->id == 0){unset $followers[$key]}
}
```

is there a better more efficient way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an array not an object, so why are you accessing as an object?

Try this,

```
foreach ($followers as $key => $follower) {
    if($followers[$key] == 0) {
        unset($followers[$key]);
    }
}
```

1. You were accessing values of an array like an object.
2. You were using `unset` incorrectly.
3. You were missing the `;` at the end of your `unset` part.

Comment: That's not what I really needed, I mislead you, thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

What I really need is removing an item from array of arrays in my Cache I tried this:

```
if(Cache::has('user_follower'.$user_id)){
        $user_follower = Cache::get('user_follower'.$user_id);

        foreach($user_follower as $key=>$follower){
            if($follower->user_id == Auth::id()){
                unset($user_follower[$key]);
                Cache::put('user_follower'.$user_id, $user_follower, 30);
                return;
            }
        }

}
```

I failed sadly, so I'm for now I'm using Cache::forget.